# Java memory - heap and non-heap items

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

which of these in the JVM memory model are part of heap and which are outside heap?

1. PS Survivor Space
2. Eden Space
3. PS Eden Space
4. CMS Perm Gen
5. Code Cache
6. Compressed Class Space
7. PS Old Gen
8. PS Survivor Space
9. Metaspace
10. Tenured Gen
11. CMS Old Gen
12. Survivor Space
13. Par Eden Space

Comment: How these regions are defined is dependent on GC and has nothing to do with the JVM memory model. The JVM memory model is concerned with things like thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

- PS Survivor Space = Heap
- Eden Space = Heap
- PS Eden Space = Heap
- CMS
- Perm Gen = Non Heap
- Code Cache = Non Heap
- Compressed Class Space = Non Heap
- PS Old Gen = Heap
- PS Survivor Space = Heap
- Metaspace = Non
- Heap Tenured Gen = Heap
- CMS Old Gen = Heap
- Survivor Space = Heap
- Par Eden Space = Heap

[image: Memory Model]

[image]